# Pusher auth endpoint responded with html, how to fix this?

Tags: laravel, pusher

I am currently using laravel 5.8 and pusher 3.0.3 and I am new to these new tech. I have created a simple chatroom but failed to listen to presence channel using `pusher`. I previously tried `Echo` but I can't find a way to debug it.

Here is `pusher:subscription_error` from the console:

```
Pusher: JSON returned from webapp was invalid, yet status code was 200. Data was: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I have already added this line to my `BroadcastServiceProvider.php`

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
require base_path('routes/channels.php');
```

I have already receive events from pusher debugger with public channel so I think I have set my credentials correctly.

This is the buttom part of my `bootstrap.js`.

```
const CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

var pusher = new Pusher('61540f91921896045e25', {
    cluster: "ap1",
    forceTLS: true,
    //authEndpoint: 'authchatuser'
    authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
    auth: {
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': CSRF_TOKEN
      }
    }
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('presence-chatroom');

//var channel = pusher.subscribe('chatroom');
channel.bind('MessagePosted', function(data) {
   console.loga(data);
});

channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function(data) {
   console.log("Pusher: " + data);
});
```

From the network tab, I couldn't see request to my pusher authEndpoint `broadcasting/auth`, but instead I see `GET` request to my homepage which responded with `200` which I think is the reason why I receive `html` instead of `json`.

Please help me with this or do you have idea to bypass the endpoint and send json data for authentication (correct data expected by pusher) instead from my `web.php`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to bypass the endpoint, but instead you should amend your endpoint to return the correct data.
Your authentication endpoint should return a JSON body along with a HTTP code. [The documentation](https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#authEndpoint) states:

> Successful responses from an authentication endpoint should carry a
> 200 OK HTTP status and a body of the form
> `{ "auth": $AUTHORIZATION_STRING   }`

This aligns with the error you are receiving which indicates that JSON is expected but HTML is received.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way that I could somehow include data from the pusher init so that I could tell to the endpoint that I needed a json? Or is the problem might be in my broadcast service provider? Or the routes? If only I know what pusher expects from the `auth` property of the response, then maybe I can make it from a custom endpoint.